# How to reproduce this effect of Voronoi cells made from custom points?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to copy effect from below video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i192IQ5KTA&ab_channel=HadrienBrissaud

Unfortunately video doesn't provide important information. For example, what is the input geometry.

File with my progress: [image]

Screenshot of the effect

[image: Screenshot of the effect]

Comment: link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i192IQ5KTA

Comment: hello, so isn't the youtube video supposed to explain how to do it?

Comment: @moonboots It doesn't. It only shows the result.

Comment: Can you convert this texture to mesh?

Comment: @saded I don't know. I was not able to reproduce the result yet.

Comment: @healthyfat The video shows all the nodes that are used to create this. But if you do not want to go through it and recreate it step by step, do you expect us to do this for you?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Of course not. Don't be silly. I did copy the node tree, but I am missing some critical information, which video doesn't provide and this where I need help to figure out. For example I don't know what is the input geometry. There is 2 objects in collection. One is the grid obviously, but what is the other. 

I can provide file if necessary.

Comment: Well, that sounds like we could help... just saying you want to recreate it but do not know how is something different than having built the node tree and maybe just missing one thing which does not work. Your file could be helpful, otherwise we would have to build all by ourselves from the video and still have no idea where your node tree is missing something...

Comment: File with my progress included.

Comment: @healthyfat Looks to me like the inputs objects are a flat plane at the top, that displays the texture. A 12x12 grid created with the geo nodes set up, that is modified with noise to be random. And a random group of vertices from the Object node, that you can move around in edit mode and add vertices to. He's switching between the two with the Switch node, I don't think that random collection of vertices and the grid interact with each other.

Comment: Maybe you can add a plane, then add Cell fracture with geometry nodes!.

Comment: Your .blend file is also missing a shader using attributes from the GN.
The input object is effectively a flat plane subdivided several times. The subdivision is mandatory to see the Voronoi effect.

Comment: If you read the comments under the youtube video, you will see that @hadriscus provides a link with the .blend file. (slightly different from the video, but with everything you need)